Angular: Filter nested mat-table in Angular Material
I have a table developed with mat-table in Angular where each row have it's own table which gets visible when expanded each row. The view is working as expected but I need to have a global filter option were the string will be searched in the parent table and return the rows where the string has been found in the child table. The child table also should have only the rows that have it's first column's value matching with the searched string.
Here my search logic is working to fetch the rows correctly from the parent table. However in th child table, the whole table is showing instead of the specific rows.
Here is my stackblitz solution where I've replicated my UI.
In the TS, inside onSubmit() function you can see I've written the logic fo filtering the table starting from Ln 93 - 107.
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) => {
  let childDataSource: any[] = data['childs'];
  childDataSource = childDataSource.filter(e => {
    return e?.['memberName']?.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter) || e?.['objectName']?.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter)
  });
  this.setChildDataSource(childDataSource);
  return childDataSource.length>0;
};
this.searchValue.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.dataSource.filter = value?.toLowerCase()?.trim());

Even though in this code the pass the filtered data in setChildDataSource(...) it is not getting reflected. I debugged and found that the same method is being used from the HTML also where it is getting called from dataSource for the inner table which is reverting my filtered data.
Can anyone help me out to solve it?

